# Initializing vector with reference_wrappers

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list, reference-wrapper

I am trying to run an example with vector of reference wrappers, but run into compilation error at the vector variable declaration. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

struct X1: public Base
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "X1\n";
    }
};

struct X2: public Base
{
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "X2\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    X1 x1;
    X2 x2;
    vector<reference_wrapper<Base>> X{cref(x1), cref(x2)};
}
```

The vector constructor with `std::initializer_list` exists. The type of the passed values must be `const T`, which `std::cref` returns, so why does it complain:

```
/home/u1/sandbox/c++/trash/untitled/main.cpp:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Base> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     vector<reference_wrapper<Base>> X{cref(x1), cref(x2)};
                                                         ^
```

?
(building with gcc -std=c++17 if it matters)

Answer (score 5):

You're initializing a non-`const` `Base` with `const` wrappers:

```
vector<reference_wrapper<Base>> X{cref(x1), cref(x2)};
```

use `const Base` instead:

```
vector<reference_wrapper<const Base>> X{cref(x1), cref(x2)};
```

Comment: Tried ``const Base`` for template argument as well as ``Base`` with ``std::ref`` (instead of ``std::cref``) to no avail.

Comment: @Student4K Either use `const Base` with `std::cref` or `Base` with `std::ref`. Both work for me: https://wandbox.org/permlink/DxpPdk3q1WDSB6uy. Note that `const Base` works even with `std::ref`.

Comment: Hm... looks like only gcc 9.x compiles the code, whereas 7.x and 8.x do not.